# How to prevent double orders when a pay pal notifications comes in from pay pal but also the web order shows pending?

Tags: paypal, notifications

We have a company that designed our website and we have pay pal standard set up to take payments.  It works great except for theres times where there is a double order because the notifications from paypal go to one sales person and another sales guy handles the website orders.  The notifications could be from more than just the website so the sales guy doesn't think anything of it when putting in the order and the notification however doesn't update on our website if the order is filed by that sales person and vis versa.  Also we run into the issue of the shipping and billing addresses being different and matching them since the website shows who its going to as the main name and the pay pal will show the billing name.  Any suggestions on what we can do to make it easier on our sales team?

Answer (score 0):

I would HIGHLY recommend you implement [paypal-ipn](/questions/tagged/paypal-ipn) and process the orders into your system that way. That notice would let you use a program to process the order data into your system and avoid issues like multiple entries, keying errors, etc.